# Mysterious Deaths, or is it just a well known attack?

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

Last week you were promoted to the position of Sergeant Head Detective of Australia, which basically means the best detective in Australia. Its January 2019, and you wake up ready for your new job.

But on your first day, you get a phone call from your best friend Sergeant Jack:

> Sergeant Corrus Onavir, we have a death at 11 Vircor Avenue* Please come immediately and...

The phone was suddenly cut. Startled, you open the front door of your office and bolt down the stairs, and get to the scene as quickly as possible.

Once you get there, you see a teenaged boy, dead at his own house in his apartment. There was a name id, and you quickly glance at it. The name was Charlie Olthe, 19 years old.

*That might be important* you think, and you go look at everything else. Beside him was a clock stopped at 1am, a tissue, and a small squishy ball with tiny spikes coming out of it. No fingerprints, nothing on the body: It was a really weird death. Just as you were about to leave, you see a piece of paper that looks like it says BIN. No conclusions were to be found, but the case wasn't closed. You thought about it, and went back to your office.

The next day, Jack called you again. This time, they had already inVestigated the death and told him everything they knew:

A clock that stopped at 9am, the exact same squishy ball, again nothing on the site on the body, and the name was Victoria Ivey, and she was only 11 years old. Again, there was another piece of paper that he said looked like an AR. You thought about it, but still nothing came to your mind. Aghast, you went back to your office for 2 hours, before you were called again at 1pm to another death scene.

Once you arrived to the scene, you saw that everything that happened in the last 2 deaths were there.   *They must be connected somehow* you thought, as you saw the squishy ball with spikes, the clock that stopped at 1pm, the piece of paper that said Y, and the name id, except only his first name was seen. It was David. You thought about it, still not knowing what was happening. But then, on the edge of peripheral vision, you saw a 2 pieces of paper dangling in the air. You go and investigate.

It wrote:

> You want to know who killed them? Heres' a Nurikabe puzzle answer... wait parts are erased! White is bigger than Black...  Solve it if you can!

[image: Nurikabe Puzzle]

After solving the puzzle, some suspects were sent to your office. You dismiss all of them, saying that they aren't the murderers. You go out of your office, and start telling everyone to be careful.

Your task:

1. Find who/or what killed them and why
2. How the title fits in
3. Why Corrus Onavir?
4. All other references to the answer.

Good luck!

*Made up place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This puzzle is a reference to the

> coronavirus:
>
>  The name "Corrus Onavir" can be rearranged as `COR[ONAVIR]RUS`, with an extra R.   >! Similarly, the location "Vircor Avenue" is two of the syllables from the word "coronavirus".
>
>  The "squishy ball with spikes coming out" is a common way of depicting the coronavirus.
>  The names' initials spell out C.O., V.I., D.

The Nurikabe has multiple solutions, and I'm not sure how it's relevant:

> [image]
>  (In the 11 region, you can shade R5C3 or R7C3; you could also connect the given black cell the other way.)
>
>  The "pieces of paper" spell BINARY, but the rows and columns don't read as meaningful ASCII, with either assignment of 0/1.

Comment: Change the rows to binary: what are the only numbers that appear?

Comment: The nurikabe puzzle is also wrong. count again 11 or 12?

Comment: There are some more references to Covid (coronavirus), maybe you could find them all. (If i can count correctly, theres 4)

Comment: @102152111 Oh, I miscounted. Then the puzzle is not unique.

Comment: The intended puzzle solution was to make the R7C3 shaded, not R5C3 shaded. (in my tests solves, along with bobble, that wasn't seen) Having that in mind, now go try convert into binary :what are the only nnumbers that appear?